# Cell seems to "failed", but there's not explanation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm running my Jupyter notebook as always, and there's one cell that has an "x" at the bottom:
[image]

The cell runs and finishes the plot I'm doing, but I can't figure out why there's and "x" there. Also, usually when one cell fails the next cells after it in the notebook don't run. But everything ran just fine -- except for this cell

Don't know if this will help, but the code for the cell is:

```
W = net.fc1.weight
W = W.detach().numpy()

svd = decomposition.TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
W1_dec = svd.fit_transform(W.T)
x = W1_dec[:,0]
y = W1_dec[:,1]
plot = sns.scatterplot(x, y)

for i in range(0,W1_dec.shape[0]):
     plot.text(x[i], y[i]+2e-2, list(vocabulary.keys())[i], horizontalalignment='center', size='small', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

Comment: How about clicking the button `clear outputs` and `restart` in the top of Jupyter, does the error logo go away? and the code you post can't be executed because `net`, `decomposition` and `vocabulary` is not defined, that i can't reproduce your question.

Comment: Yea the code is quite long so I didn't want to post the entire thing. Clicking `clear outputs` or `restart` did not remove the `x`. `net` is just a neural network, `vocabulary` is a dictionary, and for `decomposition`, the code is `from sklearn import decomposition`

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Can you please put a report in [vscode-jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues?q=) and share the link here?